# Maven surefire not detecting junit5 tests

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using   3.0.0-M5 surefire-plugin.version in quarkus pom.xml.

I have also added the below dependency in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  35.575 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-23T09:32:16+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where is the source code of your tests in your directory tree?

Comment: Source code is under src->main->java->com.example->Source.java
, Test file is under src->test->java->com.example->SourceTest.java

Comment: Please show an example test...

Comment: Can you try plugin version 2.22.0? I had a similar problem and downgrading fixed it for me.